# How to install GDAL with Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, gdal, windows-10

I am trying to install the GDAL library with Python on Windows 10. The Python version is MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64). The setup files (core and GDAL binaries) are from [Tamas Szekeres’ Windows binaries](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) based on the Python version.  Path Variables were set up but after testing (gdalinfo --version), the terminal did not show it was installed successfully. 
Checking the C:\Program Files list, the GDAL files did not show up.

I am wondering how I can install GDAL with Python on Windows 10 successfully?

Comment: So you used the MSI installers, or?

Comment: the way I did it is first install GDAL, then install the MSI python installer for the GDAL version you installed and made sure it was for my correct python version

Comment: I vaguely remember having to custom set the install path to lib/site_packages and it should show up in the osgeo folder

Comment: http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for your reply. yes, I used the .msi file to install GDAL.

Comment: @ziggy, Thanks for your reply. When I ran the installer for the GDAL python bindings, the step which set up the location of installing shows it can be installed in the Python location.

Comment: @ziggy the osgeo folder is in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\osgeo

Comment: so in python try this: from osgeo import gdal

Comment: @ziggy  Well, actually, I used the gdal wheel to install it at first. I can import the gdal in a python script. However, when I applied a gdal command (gdal_megery.py) to megery three geotiff files using subprocess.call with a python script,  the windows terminal cannot execute the command. It shows 'The system cannot find the file specified'. Then, I tried the binaries method to install GDAL. But, it still cannot work.

Comment: BTW, when I execute any commands, the terminal  always warns  **'ogr2ogr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**. But, when I use the Python script to call gdalwarp, it can work to export the reprojected raster images.

Comment: Did you open the command window through the Windows program menu GDAL - GDAL Command Prompt? That is actually running a command like C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\GDALShell.bat". I seem to have 32-bit version on this computer. The script is setting the environment correctly for GDAL programs.

Comment: @user30184 What do you mean. You mean did I open the command prompt with Python code? Like shell = Ture or False? Or did I use the Windows terminal to execute the command?

Comment: I mean that the error "ogr2ogr' is not recognized as an internal or external command," means that you have tried to run it so that the environment variables (paths, mainly) are not correctly set. That may not affect Python but for sure GDAL executables.

Comment: Oh right, I see. But my menu does not have the GDAL Command Prompt. For the environment variables, I add C:\Program Files\GDAL to Path. However, I even cannot find the GDAL fold in the C:\Program Files! So I thought there are some problems of GDAL installation!

Comment: I'm working on installing gdal on my windows 10 machine and making it available through git bash on the command line. Help would be appreciated. I ended up following @Alex Lilith's advice and used the OSgeo4w installer.I have also added the folder for C:\OSGeo4W\bin\ to my path, via this computer --> properties --> advanced settings --> environment variables on the graphical interface. But typing in `gdal tools` to the command line still gets me `$ gdal tools bash: gdal: command not found`
and also, I tried using git bash's `env|grep PATH` command. I noticed at first it wasn't printing out the

Comment: https://frew.eri.ucsb.edu/private/ESM296-2/general/GDAL.html

I followed instructions here, but I added a line to `.bash_profile` with `export PATH="/c/OSGeo4W/bin:$PATH"` and now `gdalinfo --version` (as a command in git bash) returns  `GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19`
However, `gdal` itself is still an unrecognized command

Comment: https://gisforthought.com/setting-up-your-gdal-and-ogr-environmental-variables/
Followed instructions here on setting gdal and ogr environmental variables and now the command ogr2ogr works on cmd prompt and git bash.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/140726)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend [installing GDAL using OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/), which will set up an environment where all these tools will work nicely together.

You may have some luck using the new package management tool for Windows, [Chocolately](https://chocolatey.org/), but I haven't tried it yet for GDAL (it worked really well to install NPM and other tools for me, though, and seems to be the sensible option these days).

Comment: Wow, OSGeo4W works as a shell. I never used it before. Thanks for your answer. I will try it. But I am not sure I can call the shell in a python script to execute a gdal command.

Comment: Hi @YuhaoWu, you can definitely add the bin folder from OSGeo4W to your path, and then can call gdal tools from there ;-)

Comment: So after I add the bin folder to the Environment Variables, I can call the gdal tools?  and I can call the gdal tool with Python code? Sorry,could you please tell me more about how to call it with python? Thanks

Comment: I got it, thank you so much. I used shell to run python script. So when script call the terminal, the shell is used to execute the command.